# Anti-debugging how to deal with library patching?

Tags: iphone, c, debugging, android-ndk

Does anyone know of a standard technique addressing the following problem:

- I want to detect, if a debugger is attached to my program (anti-debugging)
- However the attacker patches the system calls/libraries that I use

For example on iOS the sysctl()-function can be used to detect an attached debugger, but the attacker simply disassembles the binary executable, finds the sysctl()-calls, and replaces them with his own version.

How do we as developers deal with this?

My platforms are iOS (iPhone) and native Android (Android NDK).

Comment: What if the "attacker" runs your code in a simulator and uses that to single step the code? No debugger at all...

Comment: Question: Would single-stepping in the simulator not be detected with sysctl()?

However I consider recording the time before a critical code and after a critical code. If the time span is long, I could conclude that the program is being debugged. However what if an attacker patches the time()-call? It is a variation of the original posted question.

Answer (score 7):

Perfect detection of a debugger is logically impossible. The specification of a machine on which a program runs does not specify a particular piece of silicon or other physical object—it specifies the behavior of a machine. **Any** implementation that provides the behavior as described by the specification **is** an implementation of the machine. This includes executing the program on a physical processor that implements the specification, it includes executing the program in a simulator that implements the specification, and it includes a human reading the machine code and implementing the machine on paper. These are not “just” emulations; they actually are implementations of the machine.

When the machine is correctly implemented, it is impossible for a program to determine that the machine is not correctly implemented, because of course there is no deviation from the specification. Yet we can clearly see that the actions and state of some of these machines are completely observable by a human and can be manipulated at will. Therefore, it is logically impossible to always detect the presence of a debugger.

At best, you can make it a nuisance to use a debugger and can obscure the means by which you are doing so. This can deter casual investigators but cannot stop a determined investigator.

Answer (score 1):

The golden standard of obfuscating native code is Skype, which had not been hacked for more than a decade. You can look at http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-biondi/bh-eu-06-biondi-up.pdf for a list of some Skype's obfuscation features like runtime deciphering of the machine code, resistance to debuggers and virtual machines, advanced use of cryptography and integrity checking, etc.
But any obfuscation technique known to you from external sources is already known for a code attacker, so you must put your own wizardry in it (and always there is an attacker smarter than you).

Conclusion: obfuscating native code is just setting some obstacles for an attacker, and breaking these obstacles is just matter of time and effort. 
Another way to circumvent this is keeping all the secret code on the server side of a client-server system, using a mature client-server protocol and open-sourcing the client code.